# Trouble with simple operations in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on the second homework assignment for my Assembly class, and I'm running into trouble doing even the most basic things. The assignment involves reading several lines of input from the user, where each line contains up to 8 characters (a "token") followed by an integer representing the "type" of the token. We then store it in a "symbol table" with the location of each token and a value called "DEFN" with the value of 0 or 1 that tells whether it is a label or a variable.

Right now I'm working on the "getTokens" function, which should be a loop that continually asks the user for input until it encounters a token that starts with the # character, at which point it finishes and runs the rest of the program. In getTokens, I need to read two words which make up the token, then an integer, and store them sequentially in the "inArr" array. What I'm having trouble with is storing the information in the array. As I have it now, I enter one input and the loop terminates. I see in memory that "loop" and a second word just containing 3 spaces and a \0 character appear, but I don't see the integer anywhere.

Can someone look through this and tell me what the problem might be?

```
getTokens:
    li  $t0, 0  # For keeping track of how many inputs the user has already entered.
tokenLoop:
    # First, print the token prompt.
    la  $a0, prompt    # <--- prompt contains "Enter tokens:\n"
    li  $v0, 4         # <--- system code for printing a string
    syscall

    # Read the token into inArr($t0)
    la  $a0, inArr($t0)    # <--- load the token into inArr at current pos
    li  $a1, 8             # <--- length of buffer is 8 (2 words)
    li  $v0, 8             # <--- system code for reading a string
    syscall

    # Read the integer representing the type into inArr+8($t0)
    li  $v0, 5              # system code for reading an integer
    syscall
    la  $s0, inArr+8($t0)   # supposed to copy $v0 into inArr+8($t0)...
    move    $s0, $v0

    # Add 12 to $t0.
    addi    $t0, $t0, 12    # <--- increment by 12 (2 words + 1 int = 12)

    # If the first character of the token is #, end the token input. Else, restart the input loop.
    lb  $t1, inArr($t0)        # get first character of token (from first word)
    bne $t1, '#', tokenLoop

    jr  $ra
```

And if it helps, here's a sample input from the user.

```
Enter tokens:
loop    2
:       4
beqz    2
$       5
t1      2
,       4
next    2
#       6   <--- At this point, loop terminates because token is '#'
```

Comment: `move    $s0, $v0` should be `sw $v0, ($s0)` to store the integer input into memory at address `$s0` that you have set previously.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but now, where the integer representing the type should be, I just see a period character. What could be causing that? My professor said we need to enter the token followed by enough spaces so that the token is 8 exactly, THEN the integer for the type.

Comment: Yeah, because you first read 8 characters into the token, so if you don't pad the input then the type will also be read into the token. Note that the integer is in binary, so the period is because it is not a printable ascii code. Look at the numeric value.

Comment: How do I do that? I should mention that my professor has done a horrible job of explaining MIPS in the first place, and a lot of the class has no idea what they're doing. He does such a poor job that I've heard people who have taken the class in the past say that he has to scale the final grades by like 30 points so people don't fail.

Comment: Depends on what emulator or tool you use. It should be obvious how to examine the numeric value, I hope you can figure it out.

Comment: I'm using MARS. I'm looking at the "data segment" in the execute tab with "ASCII" checked off so I can see the text in memory.

Comment: According to my googling you should check `hex values` ... come on, you should have found that out...

Comment: I would appreciate if you wouldn't just assume I know what I'm doing, because as I said, everyone in my class is completely lost. I'm not even sure I know what this function is supposed to do anymore.

Comment: Also, my professor responded to my email and said that we don't need to read two words and an integer... we just need to read three words. But that still doesn't tell me why my "bne" condition is causing my loop to only take one input before it finishes. Also, if I enter "#" as the token, the program terminates with errors.